# Write a program that accepts two numbers and an operator, like (+,-), as command line arguments and perform the operation indicated by operator

Tags: c

So, I'm trying to write a program that allows the user to input two integers and then an operator (plus or minus) and find the result of adding/subtracting the two values.

For example, if the user types in: `2 3 +`
the code will display: `2 + 3 = 5`

If the user forgets to add in the plus or minus sign an error message should come up saying `invalid entry`. So far I've only been able to make a program that accepts two integers that are written separately and then just does an addition.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main() {
   int integer1, integer2, sum;  // Declare 3 integer variables

   printf("Enter first integer: ");   // Display a prompting message
   scanf("%d", &integer1);            // Read input from keyboard into integer1
   printf("Enter second integer: ");  // Display a prompting message
   scanf("%d", &integer2);            // Read input into integer2


   sum = integer1 + integer2;         // Compute the sum

   // Print the result
   printf("The sum of %d and %d is %d.\n", integer1, integer2, sum);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't spam language tags! You might want to read [ask] first. What was the question?

Comment: So you're asking how to input the operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could read the whole expression,like 2+3, in one `scanf()` statement and then compare the operator to determine what to do.

```
   int integer1, integer2, sum;// Declare 3 integer variables
   char oper;//this is where you read the operator as character

   printf("Enter an expression: ");// Display a prompting message

   // Read expression like 2+3,2 +3,2 + 3... from user
   int res=scanf("%d %c%d", &integer1,&oper,&integer2);

   //we expect 3 fields to be converted and assigned by scanf
   if(res<3)//this will catch expressions like 2+h,...
   { 
       printf("Input error");
       return 1;
   }

   switch(oper)
   {
      case '+':
         sum = integer1 + integer2;// Compute the sum
         printf("The sum of %d and %d is %d.\n", integer1, integer2, sum);
         break;
      case '-':
         sum = integer1 - integer2;// Compute the difference
         printf("The difference of %d and %d is %d.\n", integer1, integer2, sum);
         break;
      default:
         printf("Invalid entry");
   }
```

Comment: oh this is perfect! Very clear and easy to understand.

Comment: @chux right! thanks for  the feedback.

Answer (score 4):

Get the operator from the user and store it as a char.  Then compare the operator to the plus sign, '+', and the minus sign,'-'.  If it matches one of those, do that operation.  If it doesn't, print your error message.

```
char operator;

if(operator == '+')
    sum = integer1 + integer2;
else if(operator == '-')
    sum = integer1 - integer2;
else
{
    printf("Error");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: lets say i wanted to get all the values (including the operator) in one line how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Take a look at bkVnet's answer.  He does a nice job of expanding on what I wrote and adding the functionality you are asking about.